# Insert new columns only when ID is the same in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 worksheets with similar table structures which looks like this:

```
|   ID   |   A   |   B   |   C   |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1    |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|   4    |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|   12   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|   3    |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|        |
| ... (thousands of rows)
```

where x are values. Is it possible to create a new table (or worksheet) combining the two worksheets only where the ID from Worksheet1 is the same (similar to a SQL query) so that the resulting table will be like:

```
|   ID   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1    |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|   4    |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|   12   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|   3    |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|        |
| etc...
```

Note that the contents of Worksheet1 is added to and not subtracted from. Is VBA necessary or can it be done with a formula? Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, I've accomplished my goal by importing the two worksheets as tables in Access and combining them with a query `SELECT ID, Var1, Var2 etc. FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID`. I'm just wondering now how this can be done in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlookup to solve this.

vlookup searches for id in sheet2 and returns corresponding value in your specified column number of the selected table.